# When I try to convert nonetype variable to string it does not change? Is there any better way to store dates?

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.8

I was making a program to store dates in an Excel sheet to make a task simpler, and then I encountered this confusion of how to generate or how to store dates from which I can easily write them to the Excel sheet.

I have provided the code below if anyone wants to try:

```py
to_day = int(input("Enter the day today: "))
to_month = int(input("Enter the month: "))
to_year = int(input("Enter the year you are in: "))
today_date = print(to_day, "-", to_month, "-", to_year)
str_todaydate = str(today_date)
print(type(today_date))
```

Comment: You do not need to ask the user to input today's date. You can just get today's date by doing `datetime.datetime.today().date()`

Comment: `print` doesn't return anything, it's not a way to concatenate strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print` returns `None`, not the string that got printed.  Change this:

```
today_date = print(to_day, "-", to_month, "-", to_year)
```

to this:

```
today_date = f"{to_day}-{to_month}-{to_year}"
print(today_date)
```